# Promises: How to handle errors in the middle of promises chaining

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm currently chaining some promises from Firebase database with some other ones from Stripe api. I would like to know what is the best way to handle the following situation:

```
   firebase.database().ref('orders').push(**a new order object**)
      .then((snap) => {
        //I get back the saved object from the database, and in particular its unique Id
        orderId = snap.key;
        //I then create a stripe Source
        return stripe.createSource({
          type: '....',
          amount: ...,
          currency: '....',
          ...
          metadata: {
            orderId: orderId
          }
        })
      })
      .then((result) => {
        //here is my problem!! 
        //the result of the stripe source creation is either a
        // a result.source -i.e. success- or a result.error 
        if (result.source) {
          //here I can continue the flow and return a value
        } else if (result.error) {
          // But here, ideally I should somehow emit an error that should be catched by the catch below. 
          //How to do that the correct way??
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {

      })
```

Comment: Just `throw` it?

Comment: you can throw it, or you can return a rejected promise. Throwing is much simpler.

Comment: Just use `throw result.error;`  That will make the promise chain become rejected and your next `.catch()` will catch the error.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like;

```
.then(r => r.source ? doSomethingWith(r.source)
                    : Promise.reject(r.error))
.catch(handleError);
```